# Change the value of a vector element

Tags: vector, cobol

I want to change the value of the first element in my vector (which is set to 1 ) in this case, by adding 1 to it - but also ,other,more complicated arithmetics.  here is the code:

```
*************************************************************
           IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
           PROGRAM-ID. YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
           DATA DIVISION.
           FILE SECTION.
               WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
               01 TABLE1.
                   05 BERN PIC 9(1) OCCURS 10 TIMES VALUE 1.
           PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           MAIN-PROCEDURE.
               COMPUTE BERN(1) = BERN(1)+1.
               DISPLAY TABLE1.
               STOP RUN.
           END PROGRAM YOUR-PROGRAM-NAME.
```

The problem is that it doesn't accept

```
 COMPUTE BERN(1) = BERN(1)+1.
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Why jam everything up against each other? It looks shoddy and is less easy to change. `COMPUTE BERN ( 1 )  =  BERN ( 1 ) + 1`. There. That'll compile. Note the suggestion about the `ADD`. Much more descriptive here. Also look for comment here about full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION with post-1985 COBOL. Note also the comment about "does VALUE 1 work there?". You never want to hear those type of comments, where someone has to look at a manual to understand your code. So, simplify.

Comment: You spotted the problem with your table on the Benoulli question?

Comment: yes @BillWoodger I did, the problem was : The variable RES and the vector element variables - they where getting overflowed with  "N" got bigger and bigger... Do you want me to undelete that question?

Comment: What I was going to suggest was that once you'd made the fixes you may want to consider putting the question on another Stackoverflow site, Code Review. There people can comment on working code, which can be a good way for you to learn. Up to the 20th number, just changing your table entries to S9(6)V... works. But why do the calculation, and lose precision, why not just report the fractional results?

Comment: @BillWoodger, Just joined that forum!! thanks .   I didn't know one could just report the fractional result - I will look it up!

Comment: Keep both elements as integers. The numbers are naturally fractions. Why make them decimals? Changes the pseudo-code slightly, so if your order was to implement it exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COMPUTE BERN(1) = BERN(1) + 1
```

You miss the spaces. I checked with [GnuCOBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-cobol/info) on [OpenCobolIDE](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/), it works with the spaces, and does not compile without.

That being said, a good old `ADD 1 TO BERN(1)` should work too.

Comment: Ha. Whilst I was typing my comment... why be selective about the spacing?

Comment: @BillWoodger : well, I focused on the question. If it was on Code review, I would have been far more verbose. Spacing, as you said, but also points in excess. And the lack of readability of the VALUE after the OCCURS(it works, to my surprise)

Comment: Yes, the VALUE for items in a table is a COBOL 85 thing, but sticking it on the definition with the OCCURS as well is just asking too much for the reader. Wastes minutes and breaks train of thought when coming upon things like that. It just doesn't "look" right, either :-)